# A contest of curious creatures

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A new riddle by me - I don't think a line-by-line analysis is strictly necessary, but if you could cover off the various peculiarities that would be super.

> I have eleven limbs,
>   Which can all rotate and swap.
>   I can slip, I can sweep,
>   But never with a mop.
>
> I have a few legs,
>   Sometimes short, Sometimes square,
>   They've even been called fine -
>   By those who really care.
>
> I can cover and I can point,
>   I can have a bovine on a bend!
>   But I go out to do battle,
>   Not to make a friend.
>
> My foe, though, is different,
>   He is armed, it is true.
>   He comes out to fight me,
>   But his limbs are only two.
>
> Cut one off, though
>   And you will quickly see,
>   Another one replaces it
>   But not for eternity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a cricketing team fielding.

Your eleven limbs are

> the players.

The terms

> slip, sweep, short leg, square leg, fine leg, cover(s), point, cow corner, all describe fielding positions. Except that, er, so far as I can tell "sweep" is only the name of a thing a batsman does, so I'm a bit confused about that.

Your foe is

> the opposing team. Only two of them are playing at a given time, but if you get one of them out another takes their place -- until 10 are out and they have to stop.

And of course

> "cricket", like "contest", "curious" and "creatures", begins with a C.

Comment: Perfectly answered, and correct of course. Regarding the term you're not sure on: r13(N fjrrcre vf n nygreangvir anzr sbe gur fcbg nebhaq qrrc rkgen pbire. Ng yrnfg vg vf va AM - zvtug abg or n tybony guvat.)

Comment: Ah, OK. My ignorance of this stuff is boundless.